# In Go, how do you handle multiple ABI's from Abigen?

Tags: go, package, smartcontracts, abi

The Abigen tutorials I've seen all show setting pkg=main, and this way you don't have to explicitly import packages from other go files.  But that means when you execute "go run" you have to include the go files that contain the ABI's.  If I'm using several ABI's in my code, is there a way to avoid a crazy long "go run" execution?
For example...

```
go run app.go wbnb.go busd.go tokenPair1.go tokenPair2.go tokenPair3.go factory.go
```

Comment: What happens with a simple `go run .` ?

Comment: If you're using packages from other files then you need to run them with your main file in order for it to work.  Can get cumbersome if you have a lot of abis.

Answer (score 1):

Using the w3 package worked for me.  Much simpler process for creating abi's for go.

`https://github.com/lmittmann/w3`

Example:

```
    getSymbol := w3.MustNewFunc("symbol()", "string")
    var(
        symbol string
    )

    err_symbol := client.Call(eth.CallFunc(getSymbol, wbnbAddress).Returns(&symbol))
    if err_symbol != nil {
        log.Fatal(err_symbol)
    }
    fmt.Println("symbol:", symbol)
```